# Count the number of Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

i need the query for count the number of Columns in my SQL Server table .

Comment: Please edit your question - the title and body ask two completely different things.

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tablename')

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(*) from your_table
```

counts **all** rows, even when some records contain `NULL` entries.

```
select count(some_column) from your_table
```

counts records where `some_column` `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: He wants columns not rows from the content but not the title so who knows.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
select count(*) from table
```

`*` means all columns

Comment: * does not mean all rows. It means all columns.